# ConnectionReset error while uploading to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a DRF + celery workers set up on Amazon EC2 instance. My main server is on EBS and workers are simple EC2 instances.

I am trying to upload files to S3 using the boto3 package. 
The code to upload is as follows:

```
class AmazonS3:
def __init__(self, bucket_name):
    aws_config = AWSConfig()
    session = aws_config.get_session()
    self.s3 = session.resource("s3")
    self.bucket_name = bucket_name

def upload(self, key, file_name):
    if os.path.isfile(file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as upload_file:
            try:
                logger.info("Uploading to S3 " + self.bucket_name + " " + key)
                response = self.s3.Object(self.bucket_name, key).put(Body=upload_file)
                logger.info(response)
                if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] != 200:
                    return False
            except:
                logger.error(traceback.format_exc())
                return False
        return True
    return False
```

**The problem:**

When I run this on my local machine (with local celery workers and local servers), it uploads to S3 without an error. When I try uploading the same type of file as a celery task on my server worker instance, it throws a `104 Connection Reset by peer` error. I don't understand what the server does differently. My local environment is similar to the production environment.

The errors are `104 connection reset by peer` and `broken pipe` as listed below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

 body=body, headers=headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request

 conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request

 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 122, in _send_request

 self, method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request

 self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders

 self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 157, in _send_output

 self._handle_expect_response(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 200, in _handle_expect_response

 self._send_message_body(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 227, in _send_message_body

 self.send(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 234, in send

 return HTTPConnection.send(self, str)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 885, in send

 self.sock.sendall(datablock)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 170, in sendall

 v = self.send(data_to_send)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 145, in send

 super(GreenSSLSocket, self).send, data, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 112, in _call_trampolining

 return func(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 702, in send

 v = self._sslobj.write(data) ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send

 timeout=timeout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen

 _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 245, in increment

 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 309, in reraise

 raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

 body=body, headers=headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request

 conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request

 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 122, in _send_request

 self, method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request

 self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders

 self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 157, in _send_output

 self._handle_expect_response(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 200, in _handle_expect_response

 self._send_message_body(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 227, in _send_message_body

 self.send(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 234, in send

 return HTTPConnection.send(self, str)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 885, in send

 self.sock.sendall(datablock)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 170, in sendall

 v = self.send(data_to_send)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 145, in send

 super(GreenSSLSocket, self).send, data, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 112, in _call_trampolining

 return func(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 702, in send

 v = self._sslobj.write(data) botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ubuntu/workindia-worker/workindiaapi/Developement/api/adapter/amazons3.py", line 24, in upload

 response = self.s3.Object(self.bucket_name, key).put(Body=upload_file)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 344, in do_action

 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 77, in __call__

 response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 270, in _api_call

 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 324, in _make_api_call

 operation_model, request_dict)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 110, in make_request

 return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 139, in _send_request

 success_response, exception):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 203, in _needs_retry

 caught_exception=caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit

 return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit

 response = handler(**kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__

 if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__

 caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 273, in _should_retry

 return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 313, in __call__

 caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__

 return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 355, in _check_caught_exception

 raise caught_exception   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response

 proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send

 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send

 raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

and

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

 body=body, headers=headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request

 conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request

 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 122, in _send_request

 self, method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request

 self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders

 self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 157, in _send_output

 self._handle_expect_response(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 200, in _handle_expect_response

 self._send_message_body(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 227, in _send_message_body

 self.send(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 234, in send

 return HTTPConnection.send(self, str)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 885, in send

 self.sock.sendall(datablock)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 170, in sendall

 v = self.send(data_to_send)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 145, in send

 super(GreenSSLSocket, self).send, data, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 112, in _call_trampolining

 return func(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 702, in send

 v = self._sslobj.write(data) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send

 timeout=timeout   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 597, in urlopen

 _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 245, in increment

 raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/packages/six.py", line 309, in reraise

 raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen

 body=body, headers=headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 349, in _make_request

 conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1088, in request

 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 122, in _send_request

 self, method, url, body, headers)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1126, in _send_request

 self.endheaders(body)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1084, in endheaders

 self._send_output(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 157, in _send_output

 self._handle_expect_response(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 200, in _handle_expect_response

 self._send_message_body(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 227, in _send_message_body

 self.send(message_body)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/awsrequest.py", line 234, in send

 return HTTPConnection.send(self, str)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 885, in send

 self.sock.sendall(datablock)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 170, in sendall

 v = self.send(data_to_send)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 145, in send

 super(GreenSSLSocket, self).send, data, flags)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/eventlet/green/ssl.py", line 112, in _call_trampolining

 return func(*a, **kw)   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 702, in send

 v = self._sslobj.write(data) botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/ubuntu/workindia-worker/workindiaapi/Developement/api/adapter/amazons3.py", line 24, in upload

 response = self.s3.Object(self.bucket_name, key).put(Body=upload_file)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/factory.py", line 344, in do_action

 response = action(self, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/boto3/resources/action.py", line 77, in __call__

 response = getattr(parent.meta.client, operation_name)(**params)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 270, in _api_call

 return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 324, in _make_api_call

 operation_model, request_dict)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 110, in make_request

 return self._send_request(request_dict, operation_model)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 139, in _send_request

 success_response, exception):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 203, in _needs_retry

 caught_exception=caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit

 return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit

 response = handler(**kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 183, in __call__

 if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 250, in __call__

 caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 273, in _should_retry

 return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 313, in __call__

 caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 222, in __call__

 return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 355, in _check_caught_exception

 raise caught_exception   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 167, in _get_response

 proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send

 r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 415, in send

 raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) botocore.vendored.requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', BrokenPipeError(32, 'Broken pipe'))
```